# Mongo return what inputs don't match for $IN

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way for Mongo to return some indication (flag, field, etc..) for if an input in a `$in` does not match any `docs`?

Please see my  [Mongo Playgrond](https://mongoplayground.net/p/us6izxctxkv)

That successfully just returns all odd documents.

How can I have some indication that the evens were not found?

I'd like to do this within Mongo itself. I get I can iterate through the results in `JS` and perform a `diff`.

Fwiw, I **this `$in` will actually be the first stage of a `$match` in an `aggregate`** . So maybe I can use something like `addFields` for the unmatches.

Thanks!

So my desired output could be that each negative match still gets a returning document..but with a new property `found:false` like the following. So..in my example, evens #s are not founds and it'd be cool to see something like..

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405100006"),
    "key": 2,
    "found": false
  },
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102230405000006"),
    "key": 4,
    "found": false
  },
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000122030405000006"),
    "key": 6,
    "found": false
  }
```

Maybe, it'd be cleaner to put `found` as true for all positive matches as well.

Or...maybe return an subarray of the unmatches (that could be cleaner in post-processing)

Comment: Please clarify your question, your problem is not understandable.

Comment: Also:    Please post input docs, attempted agg logic, and desired output shapes here.  SO policy is to supplement those materials with links to the outside (e.g. mongo playground), not replace.

Comment: the way you have the `$in` if not found, will return an empty cursor that you can test on your driver [see](https://mongoplayground.net/p/64vMsXrH8kc), if you can give json sample data, and expected output so we know what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight way to do this in MongoDB, You can try aggregation query to handle custom requirements,

Here I have added an aggregation query to achieve your requirement, but I am not sure what is your exact data,

**Input:**

```
[
  { "key": 1 },
  { "key": 2 },
  { "key": 3 },
  { "key": 4 },
  { "key": 50 },
  { "key": 6 },
  { "key": 7 }
]
```

- `$match` your `$in` condition
- `$facet` to separate results and not found numbers
- `result` key is to get your final document results
- `notFound` is to find the not found keys
- `$group` by null and get unique keys from result using `$addToSet`
- `$setDifference` to get the difference of two arrays, first is your input and second available result numbers
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      key: {
        $in: [1, 3, 5, 7]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      result: [],
      notFound: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            key: { $addToSet: "$key" }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            key: {
              $setDifference: [[1, 3, 5, 7], "$key"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hEl_k4TgP4d)

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "notFound": [
      { "key": [5] }
    ],
    "result": [
      { "key": 1 },
      { "key": 3 },
      { "key": 7 }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

**The second approach**, as per your expected result sample,

- `$addFields` to add new field `found`
- `$in` to check `key` has value in the provided array, if yes then return true otherwise false

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      found: {
        $in: ["$key", [1, 3, 5, 7]]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wMZ0z8ywRZr)

**Result:**

```
[
  { "key": 1, "found": true },
  { "key": 2, "found": false },
  { "key": 3, "found": true },
  { "key": 4, "found": false },
  { "key": 50,"found": false },
  { "key": 6, "found": false },
  { "key": 7, "found": true }
]
```