# find missing elements from the passed array to mongodb qyery

Tags: mongodb

for example

animals = ['cat','mat','rat'];

collection contains only 'cat' and 'mat'

I want the query to return 'rat' which is not there in collection..

collection contains

```
[
{
   _id:objectid,
   animal:'cat'

},
{
   _id:objectid,
   animal:'mat'

}
]



db.collection.find({'animal':{$nin:animals}})
(or)
db.collection.find({'animal':{$nin:['cat','mat','rat']}})
```

Comment: Is animals the collection or a key on a document?

Comment: @nimrod serok  modified the query for better understanding.

Comment: Look at the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426000/mongo-return-what-inputs-dont-match-for-in), you have to use aggregation query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
One option is:

1. Use `$facet` to `$group` all existing values to a set. using `$facet` allows to continue even if the db is empty, as @leoll2 mentioned.
2. `$project` with `$cond` to handle both cases: with or without data.
3. Find the set difference

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$facet: {data: [{$group: {_id: 0, animals: {$addToSet: "$animal"}}}]}},
  {$project: {
      data: {
        $cond: [{$gt: [{$size: "$data"}, 0]}, {$first: "$data"}, {animals: []}]
      }
  }},
  {$project: {data: "$data.animals"}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, missing: {$setDifference: [animals, "$data"]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - with data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JKMKVsK6amu) or [playground example - without data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mYmJfuh0P1f)

Comment: It does not work if the database is empty, because the set "data" is not be created in that case. The output will be empty.